# iOS UITableViewCell with asynchronously fetched image of dynamic size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I'm trying to make table view with two labels and an image in the middle. The image is fetched asynchronously from the web, and after it is fetched I want to make the UIImageView's frame to fit the size of the image, and fit the table view's width. I have set autolayout: for each label and for image only top, bottom, leading and trailing space, no height constraint.

[image]

I've set rowHeight and estimatedRowHeight in the controller:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 333.0
```

After the images are fetched, extra padding appers above and below the image (I've se the background color of image view to red, to clearly see it):

[image]

Could you help me so that there's no extra padding in the image view, but it fits the size of the image?

Comment: Have you tried to call the `layoutIfNeeded` method from UIView class?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.

Comment: If your constraints are setup correctly, auto-layout will handle the sizing of the rows. But, `UIImageView` does *not* auto-size to a scaled image... your code needs to change the Height constraint of your image view to match the scaled height of the image after it is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibility  you can go with:

1. Get width and height from server and calculate total height of cell according to width of table and label height.
2. Also, you can have a array for height of cells, where you have to store height of cell manually on every image download. and reload that particular cell on image download.

Comment: Isn't there some solution based on Auto Layout?

Comment: I tried this solution, it kinda works, at the beginning some UIViews' heights are too big, but after scrolling down and up it fixes and everything looks ok. That's weird :)

Comment: unfortunately there is no Auto Layout solution for this situation.  I personally use case 1 whenever possible. and yeah  you can  try "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths"  to get rid of big heights without scrolling manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However, reloading rows somehow has no influence on the layout, only after manual scrolling it is better...

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the UIImageView's content mode

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention, it's set to Aspect Fit

Comment: Try and change it to some other mode e.g aspect fill

Comment: Thank you for your help, when I set Aspect Fill, the padding goes away, but it still doesn't solve my problem, because the image is not fully visible, it's just cropped.